# List all table name with column value for a specific column name

Tags: mysql

Would anyone be able to help me out with this query.
I'd need to list all table name with the max date value from a column name 'Extract_Date'.
My query below only returns the list of all table name where there are column name 'Extract_Date' but I'm not sure how to list column value. Much appreciate.

```
select
    object_schema_name(t.object_id) + '.' + t.name as table_name,
    c.name as column_name
from sys.tables t
inner join sys.columns c
on t.object_id = c.object_id
where c.name like '%extract_date%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME,MAX(COLUMN_NAME) FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE table_name IN (SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='your_database_name') AND COLUMN_NAME = 'extract_date'
```

Comment: some additional information to your solution or the OP's mistake would be nice. Code-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: Thanks Navjot. I'd need to achieve one step further. List the max date in Extract_Date column for every table name.